# Spring HttpRequest get parent URL

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I have spring application which have multiple services communicating via REST.
Imagine simple

```
@RestController
```

which internally calls another rest endpoint.

When Service A calls Service B [spring httpRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRequest.html) is invoked e.g. [POST] /api/test/serviceb. Is there a way to get parent URL / endpoint of such a request ? I would like to know in Service B who calls it. How can I get that information in Spring ?

I wrote Interceptor which intercept every rest call but don't know how to get parent url for every call made.

```
public class AuditRestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution exec)
        throws IOException {
        // TODO any way to find out who call it ?
    }
}
```

Edit:
I rewrite my interceptor using **HandlerInterceptorAdapter** which has access to **HttpServletRequest**

```
public class AuditRestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditRestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
        log.info(referer); // return null

        return true;
    }
```

I tried simple call like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/runtime/case")
public class CaseController {

    @Autowired
    private CaseService caseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cidla}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CaseDto load(@PathVariable("cidla") String cidla) {
        return caseService.load(cidla);
    }
}
```

CaseService call another endpoint like this:

```
@Component
public class CaseServiceImpl implements CaseService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public CaseDto load(String cidla) {
        String host = "http://localhost:8080";
        restTemplate.getForObject(host + "/smart/api/runtime/case/{cidla}/record", RecordDto.class, cidla);
        Case c = loadCase(cidla);
        return transformCase(c);
    }
}
```

Desired behaviour - first call **/api/runtime/case/{cidla}** should return parent URL as null (I call it) then second call **/smart/api/runtime/case/{cidla}/record** should return **/api/runtime/case/{cidla}** because caseServiceImpl calls it.
 I intercept second call and tried

```
String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
```

but it will return null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL(request.getHeader("Referer")); //where request is the HttpServletRequest
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

Comment: what is "request" - what should i import what type it is ? I I google that snipped of code too but as I point out in spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRequest.html there is no "getHeader" only getHeaders and it works completely different

Comment: Request is HttpServletRequest. Modified the comment in the answer.

Comment: thanks, however I think it won't solve my problem. I updated my question. The problem is I have application which have thousands of rest endpoints. I couldn't find out a way to get to the HttpServletRequest. I already have Spring Interceptor ClientHttpRequestInterceptor which handle all rest requests however I can only pass springframework.HttpRequest there. No way to get to HttpServletRequest. Or can I somehow make custom interceptor which will be able to access this object in Spring ? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor? Do you want to modify the request based on certain conditions? Can you try `HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeader(); headers.get('Referer');` and see if this works.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have anything like 'Referer' it will return null. Nevertheless I rewrite my interceptor so it use HandlerInterceptor. I override preHandle method where I have access to HttpServletRequest. I made a simple demo where I have RestController which internally use restTemplate.getForObject("/some/another/endpoint", Pojo.class). I will catch this call and tried header.get('Referer') but I still get null. See updated question. Thanks